# Mocking a Typescript Class That Makes External API Calls

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

So I've done a lot of reading/searching, and can't seem to figure this one out.

I have a typescript class that looks like this

```
import * as Shopify from 'shopify-api-node';
export default class ShopifyService {
  private readonly shopify: Shopify;

  constructor(
    config: Shopify.IPublicShopifyConfig | Shopify.IPrivateShopifyConfig,
  ) {
    this.shopify = new Shopify({ ...config, apiVersion: SHOPIFY_API_VERSION });
  }

  public async getCurrentBulkOperation(): Promise<
    ICurrentBulkOperation | undefined
  > {
    const response = await this.shopify.graphql(bulkOperationStatusQuery);
    return response?.currentBulkOperation;
  }
}
```

This class just consists of multiple functions that make graphQL calls (this.shopify.graphql) and returns the results.

I have another file called polly.ts

```
export const pollyWolly = {

   async cons(....) {
         const shopify = new ShopifyService({ accessToken, shopName });
         const m = await shopify.getCurrentBulkOperation();
         // do stuff with m. Ex: get f from m, send f to some queue, etc etc.
   }

}
```

I am writing tests for pollyWolly. For example, the test could be hey when cons runs and shopify.getCurrentBulkOperation returns null, then make sure a message is send to some queue etc etc.

I want to MOCK shopify.getBulkOperation --> I don't want to make actual API calls to shopify... And I want to mock with different values. For example, in one test case i want to imagine that getBulkOp returned null. In another I want to image that getBulkOperation returned an object with specific fields etc.

I've read a lot of stackoverflow posts, a lot of articles, but can't seem to quite get it.

Help appreciated.

Comment: You want to test for `pollyWolly` unit, then it will be better if you mock `shopify.getCurrentBulkOperation` unit. If you want to test for `getCurrentBulkOperation`, let mock `shopify.graphql`.

Answer (score 0):

We can mock the es6 class using [Mock using module factory parameter](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#mock-using-module-factory-parameter), and use [mockFn.mockResolvedValueOnce(value)](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvalueoncevalue) method to mock the resolved value once for each test case.

E.g.

`shopifyService.ts`:

```
import Shopify from 'shopify-api-node';

const SHOPIFY_API_VERSION = '';
const bulkOperationStatusQuery = ``;

interface ICurrentBulkOperation {}

export default class ShopifyService {
  private readonly shopify: Shopify;

  constructor(config: Shopify.IPublicShopifyConfig | Shopify.IPrivateShopifyConfig) {
    this.shopify = new Shopify({ ...config, apiVersion: SHOPIFY_API_VERSION });
  }

  public async getCurrentBulkOperation(): Promise<ICurrentBulkOperation | undefined> {
    const response = await this.shopify.graphql(bulkOperationStatusQuery);
    return response?.currentBulkOperation;
  }
}
```

`polly.ts`:

```
import ShopifyService from './shopifyService';

export const pollyWolly = {
  async cons(accessToken, shopName) {
    const shopify = new ShopifyService({ accessToken, shopName });
    const m = await shopify.getCurrentBulkOperation();
    return m;
  },
};
```

`polly.test.ts`:

```
import { pollyWolly } from './polly';
import ShopifyService from './shopifyService';

const shopifyService = {
  getCurrentBulkOperation: jest.fn(),
};
jest.mock('./shopifyService', () => {
  return jest.fn(() => shopifyService);
});

describe('66790278', () => {
  const accessToken = '123';
  const shopName = 'teresa teng';
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should return value', async () => {
    shopifyService.getCurrentBulkOperation.mockResolvedValueOnce('fake value');
    const actual = await pollyWolly.cons(accessToken, shopName);
    expect(actual).toEqual('fake value');
    expect(shopifyService.getCurrentBulkOperation).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(ShopifyService).toBeCalledWith({ accessToken, shopName });
  });

  it('should return another value', async () => {
    shopifyService.getCurrentBulkOperation.mockResolvedValueOnce('another fake value');
    const actual = await pollyWolly.cons(accessToken, shopName);
    expect(actual).toEqual('another fake value');
    expect(shopifyService.getCurrentBulkOperation).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(ShopifyService).toBeCalledWith({ accessToken, shopName });
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66790278/polly.test.ts (6.536 s)
  66790278
    ✓ should return value (5 ms)
    ✓ should return another value

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.42 s
```